# error in fs from `node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js`

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

error: Error: Unable to resolve module `fs` from `node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js`: fs could not be found within the project.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to take a look into [StackOverflow: How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In order to get a prompt response you can summarize the title and what's actually your expected code behavior. It's helpful for the community.

Comment: Could you please share your code and explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm having this exact problem right now. Did you ever find a solution @Ayushi?